# How much of your base salary does this pension plan pay out upon early retirement

Tags: canada, ontario, pension-plan

Does anyone know how the [OMERS pension plan](http://www.omers.com/pension/Pensions.aspx) work in Canada? If you are a plan member for 20 years and retire early at age 55, what percent of your salary do you get as pension payout?

Comment: That's something you should ask the plan administrators.

Comment: They have an estimator .  http://www.omers.com/pension/About_myOMERS.aspx

Comment: Well, I am not yet a member, so cant access their tools. I wanted to know if somebody knows the answer :)